# Has anyone worked with aldeed:tabular package in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, tabular

I am trying aldeed:tabular package in meteor from [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular).
Here is my code

client side:

```
TabularTables = {};
Books= new Mongo.Collection('books');

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Books = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "BookList",
  collection: Books,
  columns: [
    {data: "title", title: "Title"},
    {data: "author", title: "Author"},
    {data: "copies", title: "Copies Available"},


  ]
});
```

In html file:

```
{{> tabular table=TabularTables.Books class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}
```

I can see the table formed but i am having problem in showing data in table. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you defined TabularTables only on client side? Defining it as a shared resource (eg. outside the client folder) should fix your problem.

Comment: Where exactly in common code can we place it so that it doesn't actually get initialized every single time? I.e. if you place a console.log in that file, you'll see it every time you refresh the app (even if you're not actually loading the table)